# Swift error with adding target

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code. I get an unrecognized selector sent to instance crash/error every time I tap addButton. I've looked for the past hour for an answer and can't find one. Please help.

```
@IBOutlet var addButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var resetButton: UIButton!

var number:Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let size: CGSize = self.view.frame.size;

    countLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: size.width, height: size.height/4)
    minusButton.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: size.height/4, width: size.width/2, height: size.height/8);
    addButton.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:size.height/4 + size.height/8, width: size.width, height: 5*size.height/8)
    resetButton.frame = CGRect(x:size.width/2, y: size.height/4, width: size.width/2 ,height: size.height/8)

    addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addNumber(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    minusButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(minusNumber), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    resetButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(resetNumber), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

}

func addNumber(sender: UIButton!) {
    number = number + 1
    countLabel.text = String(number)
}
```

Comment: [Edit] your question with the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addNumber(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

With

```
addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addNumber), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include sender in a selector.
 So you need to change your code to

`addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addNumber), for: .touchUpInside)`.

And you don't need to implicitly unwrap sender

`func addNumber(sender: UIButton)`

Answer (score 0):

Add `@objc` keyword before selector declaration:

```
@objc func addNumber(sender: UIButton!) {
    number = number + 1
    countLabel.text = String(number)
}
```